# REACT JS code, after SAVE (CTRL+S) change all the right syntax to a totally wrong syntax. VSCODE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, automated-refactoring

### BEFORE SAVE

[image: before ctrl s in react]

### AFTER

[image: AFTER CTRL S IN REACT]

this thing has **never happened** to me with languages like c++, etc...

in other cases it happens but for the better, for example *my html code becomes more orderly and clean.*

> the interesting fact that the code works. despite more than 20 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

[image]

See how the filename is `App.js`? That means that it will be automatically formatted for plain JavaScript.

But what you have is not plain JavaScript - you're using JSX syntax, so you need to change the file extension. Name the file `app.jsx`, and make sure to change modules that import it as well if needed.

Files that contain JSX syntax should have the file extension `.jsx`.

Only files that have no JSX syntax in them can be named `.js`.

Another option is to change the formatter for the file to React rather than just plain JavaScript, in the bottom right, eg

[image]

but fixing the file extension is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

**You probably apply the wrong format to your code**

You will need to change your formater or turn `auto format onsave` off:

Add the following to your settings.json file:

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Comment: thank you. is the extension i use doing this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change the format of the file from babel javascript to javascript react in bottom right in vs code.